# Assembler parameters type

Tags: assembly, x86, att

How can I find out what is the type of given parameter and return value in the assembler function?

What does the `lea 0x1(%ecx),%ebx` exactly do? Is the address of `0x1(%ecx)` stored in `%ebx`?

I have an assignment to rewrite assembler code to the C functions and this is the thing I don't understand. I thought that arguments are `int` because of `mov 0x8(%esp),%edx`, `mov 0xc(%esp),%eax` and return type is `int` as well, but that is probably wrong because our verification system didn't accept my solution.

Whole code is for x86, 32-bits for GNU/Linux.

I thought that the syntax of `mov` is kind of `mov <target>, <source>` but then there's `mov $0x0,%edi` and I suppose, that target can't be 0. Same with `sub $0x18,%esp`.

This is the function which is called by `toplevel_fnc`

```
080aab5c <subroutine_fnc>:
 80aab5c:   53                      push   %ebx                             // backup
 80aab5d:   8b 54 24 08             mov    0x8(%esp),%edx                   // 1st parameter pointer to the memory
 80aab61:   8b 44 24 0c             mov    0xc(%esp),%eax                   // 2nd parameter int
 80aab65:   83 f8 09                cmp    $0x9,%eax                        // if (eax == 9)
 80aab68:   74 15                   je     80aab7f <subroutine_fnc+0x23>    // true
 80aab6a:   83 f8 20                cmp    $0x20,%eax                       // else if(eax == 32)
 80aab6d:   74 10                   je     80aab7f <subroutine_fnc+0x23>    // true
 80aab6f:   3b 05 80 a9 0c 08       cmp    0x80ca980,%eax                   // else if(eax == 135047552)
 80aab75:   74 08                   je     80aab7f <subroutine_fnc+0x23>    // true
 80aab77:   c7 02 00 00 00 00       movl   $0x0,(%edx)                      // else edx = 0 -- first element in stack
 80aab7d:   eb 0e                   jmp    80aab8d <subroutine_fnc+0x31>    // jump to end programm
 80aab7f:   8b 0a                   mov    (%edx),%ecx                      // ecx = edx
 80aab81:   8d 59 01                lea    0x1(%ecx),%ebx                   // ebx = &(ecx + 1)
 80aab84:   89 1a                   mov    %ebx,(%edx)                      // edx = ebx
 80aab86:   83 f9 01                cmp    $0x1,%ecx                        // if(ecx == 1)
 80aab89:   19 d2                   sbb    %edx,%edx                        // edx = 0 and CF is set
 80aab8b:   21 d0                   and    %edx,%eax                        // 
 80aab8d:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 80aab8e:   c3                      ret
```

And this is `toplevel_fnc`

```
080aab8f <toplevel_fnc>:
 80aab8f:   55                      push   %ebp
 80aab90:   57                      push   %edi
 80aab91:   56                      push   %esi
 80aab92:   53                      push   %ebx
 80aab93:   83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp                   //24 byte for local variables
 80aab96:   c7 44 24 14 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x14(%esp)              //esp + 0x14 = 0
 80aab9d:   00 
 80aab9e:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi                    //edi = 0
 80aaba3:   8d 74 24 13             lea    0x13(%esp),%esi
 80aaba7:   8d 6c 24 14             lea    0x14(%esp),%ebp
 80aabab:   eb 2e                   jmp    80aabdb <toplevel_fnc+0x4c>
 80aabad:   0f be 44 24 13          movsbl 0x13(%esp),%eax
 80aabb2:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 80aabb6:   89 2c 24                mov    %ebp,(%esp)
 80aabb9:   e8 9e ff ff ff          call   80aab5c <subroutine_fnc>
 80aabbe:   88 44 24 13             mov    %al,0x13(%esp)
 80aabc2:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
 80aabc4:   74 12                   je     80aabd8 <toplevel_fnc+0x49>
 80aabc6:   ba 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edx
 80aabcb:   89 d3                   mov    %edx,%ebx
 80aabcd:   89 f1                   mov    %esi,%ecx
 80aabcf:   b8 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%eax
 80aabd4:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
 80aabd6:   eb 03                   jmp    80aabdb <toplevel_fnc+0x4c>
 80aabd8:   83 c7 01                add    $0x1,%edi
 80aabdb:   ba 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edx
 80aabe0:   bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
 80aabe5:   89 f1                   mov    %esi,%ecx
 80aabe7:   b8 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%eax
 80aabec:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
 80aabee:   83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
 80aabf1:   74 ba                   je     80aabad <toplevel_fnc+0x1e>
 80aabf3:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
 80aabf5:   83 c4 18                add    $0x18,%esp
 80aabf8:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 80aabf9:   5e                      pop    %esi
 80aabfa:   5f                      pop    %edi
 80aabfb:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 80aabfc:   c3                      ret
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `lea 0x1(%ecx),%ebx` is the equivalent of adding 1 to the value in _ECX_ and storing the result in _EBX_. It does so without changing any of the flags.

Comment: The first parameter loaded via `0x8(%esp),%edx` is actually a pointer to memory. You can tell this because later we access data at that memory address with instructions like `movl   $0x0,(%edx)`.

Comment: `cmp    0x80ca980,%eax` doesn't do what you think it does. Notice that it doesn't have a `$` sign on the front. That means that 0x80ca980 is a memory operand. So that instruction actually compares the 4 byte (32-bit) value at address 0x80ca980 in memory with the 32-bit value in _EAX_.

Comment: Should point out that `movl $0x0,(%edx)`  takes the 32-bit value 0x00000000 and places it at the memory address pointed to by _EDX_. It doesn't place the value 0x00000000 into _EDX_ itself.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you for your answers, so in a fact lea is sm. like a `ebx = ecx + 1` ? 
Is there a way, to find out, what is stored in the `0x80ca980` memory?
And finally, how can I know, that the parameter is pointer?

Comment: Yes it is like ebx = ecx + 1 but doesn't alter the flags (like Zero, carry etc). Using _LEA_ to add a value to a register and store it to a different register is a common usage pattern for _LEA_.

Comment: As for determining the return type you can look at `toplevel_fnc` right after the `call   80aab5c <subroutine_fnc>` . You'll see the register is being accessed as a byte since _AL_ is the lower 8-bits of the _EAX_ register. The code suggests that the return value of `subroutine_fnc` is a BYTE (8-bit char).

Comment: *"mov <target>, <source>"* - in Intel syntax yes, but you are using "AT&T" or "GAS" syntax, which has the arguments in reversed order. If you are producing those dumps by yourself with something like linux objdump, you can configure it to produce the dump in somewhat-Intel syntax by adding option `-M intel`. I'm personally strongly biased toward Intel syntax, as I find very difficult to read `cmp 0x80ca980,%eax` vs `cmp eax,[0x80ca980]` (the latter is easier for me, to notice there's memory referenced, not immediate).

Comment: @Ped7g It's "GAS" syntax. These dumps are unfortunately generated by the server, therefore I have no control over the compilation. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: @MichaelPetch so the main point of finding out what is the return value, is basically the line, when is __EAC__ accessed for the first time after call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I find out what is the type of given parameter and return value in the assembler function?

You can only make an educated guess by looking at the instructions used to store the return value in R0 (aka EAX) and looking at the data stored there. Assembly language is typeless.

> What does the lea 0x1(%ecx),%ebx exactly do? Is the address of 0x1(%ecx) stored in %ebx?

That stores the address specified by ecx + 1 in ebx. With these operands, it is effectively ebx = ecx + 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so in a fact, there is no way to determine it for sure? I mean without guessing.

Comment: It's educated guessing and debugging.